# The problem of packing items into bins? Is it NP-Complete?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I have two arrays. One array represents items. The other array represents bins with capacity. I need to find if all items can be stored in the bins. An item can only be placed in a single bin. But multiple items can be placed in the same bin.

Example,

```
Items: [10, 20, 30]
Bins: [40, 20]
Yes. Bin 1 can store items 1 and 3.  Bin 2 can store item 2.

Items: [10, 20]
Customers: [15, 15]
No. Bin 1 can store item 1, but Bin 2 cannot store item 2.
```

Comment: It is the decision version of the [Bin-Packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). The problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.  And, it can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time.

Comment: (Initially [asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70922340).)